# How to measure the rate of events through a system

Tags: math, message-queue, rate

I need to measure that rate at which a software system is consuming messages from a message queue and report on that periodically.

Specifically, messages arrive from a message queueing system and I need to report (each second) on the number of messages received within a number of rolling windows - e.g. the last second, the last 5 seconds, the last 30 seconds, etc.

Whilst I'm sure I could build this, I'm not certain that I'd go about it in the most efficient manner! I'm also sure that there are libraries for doing this (I'm using the JVM, so Apache Commons Math springs to mind), but I don't even know the right words to Google for! :-)

Comment: Any progress on this?  I have essentially the same requirement.

Comment: I ended up writing my own. I'll post it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up writing.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class BucketCounter {
    private final Lock rollLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final int[] bucketSizes;
    private final int[] buckets;
    private final int[] intervals;
    private final AtomicInteger incoming = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public BucketCounter(int... bucketSizes) {
        if (bucketSizes.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must specify at least one bucket size");
        }

        this.bucketSizes = bucketSizes;
        this.buckets = new int[bucketSizes.length];

        Arrays.sort(bucketSizes);

        if (bucketSizes[0] < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have a bucket of size < 1");
        }

        intervals = new int[bucketSizes[bucketSizes.length - 1]];
    }

    public int count(int n) {
        return incoming.addAndGet(n);
    }

    public int[] roll() {
        final int toAdd = incoming.getAndSet(0);

        rollLock.lock();
        try {
            final int[] results = new int[buckets.length];

            for (int i = 0, n = buckets.length; i < n; i++) {
                results[i] = buckets[i] = buckets[i] - intervals[bucketSizes[i] - 1] + toAdd;
            }

            System.arraycopy(intervals, 0, intervals, 1, intervals.length - 1);
            intervals[0] = toAdd;

            return results;
        } finally {
            rollLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Initialise it by passing the different time increments (e.g. 1, 5, 30). Then arrange for a background thread to call `roll()` every "time period". If you call it every second, then your buckets are 1, 5 and 30 seconds. If you call it every 5 seconds, then your buckets are 5, 25 and 150 seconds, etc. Basically, the buckets are expressed in "number of times `roll()` is called").

`roll()` also returns you an array of the current counts for each bucket. Note that these numbers are the raw counts, and are not averaged per time interval. You'll need to do that division yourself if you want to measure "rates" rather than "counts".

Finally, every time an event happens, call `count()`. I've set up a system with a few of these and I call `count(1)` on each message to count incoming messages, `count(message.size())` on each message to count incoming byte rates, etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I wanted to avoid the complexity of background threads.  I'm working on a solution based on exponential smoothing. I'll post it when I'm done.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution based on exponential smoothing.  It doesn't require any background threads.  You would create 1 instance for each rolling window that you want to track. For each relevant event you would call newEvent on each instance.

```
public class WindowedEventRate {

  private double normalizedRate; // event rate / window
  private long windowSizeTicks;
  private long lastEventTicks;


  public WindowedEventRate(int aWindowSizeSeconds) {
    windowSizeTicks = aWindowSizeSeconds * 1000L;
    lastEventTicks = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  public double newEvent() {

    long currentTicks = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long period = currentTicks - lastEventTicks;
    lastEventTicks = currentTicks;
    double normalizedFrequency = (double) windowSizeTicks / (double) period;

    double alpha = Math.min(1.0 / normalizedFrequency, 1.0);
    normalizedRate = (alpha * normalizedFrequency) + ((1.0 - alpha) * normalizedRate);
    return getRate();
  }

  public double getRate() {
    return normalizedRate * 1000L / windowSizeTicks;
  }
}
```

Comment: Fascinating. Can you explain how it works? In particular, can you explain how historical events get removed from the result?

Comment: I can try.  We want to perform exponential smoothing on the member variable normalizedRate.  Each time we get a new event we update as:
normalizedRate(t) = (normalizedFrequency * alpha) + (normalizedRate * (1 - alpha)).  Note that my implementation doesn't handle long absences of events well, i.e. it only updates normalizedRate when a new event is observed, so it will work best when the expected event rate is at least 1 per window period. I'm thinking about how this might be handled.  Today I'll try and document things better and update my answer.

Comment: More directly to your question.  So at each update we calculate a new value that is a portion of the new "measurement" and a portion of the old value.  Lookup "Exponential Smoothing" or "Kalman Filter".  I don't have a strong mathematical basis for this, but in my implementation I assign the weight of the new measurement to the proportion of the window that it represents.

Comment: It may help to see how the historical values "exponentially decay" by working through and example by hand.  You can look at start up, e.g. normalizedRate = 0 and events start occurring at a constant 2/sec or similar.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. I'll read your replies in detail and look up the references later.

Comment: If you have two or more events enter at the same tick, `normalizedFrequency` (and all other values) will be `NaN`.

Comment: FWIW this looks like an EWMA, but with a homegrown alpha definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Basic_exponential_smoothing

Answer (score -1):

You could probably implement it as an interceptor, so search for interceptor combined with the message queue product name and the language name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm not sure what it means! I have no idea what an "interceptor" is, unless you're talking about something like AOP. And the particular message queueing product and language is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @dty You may also try "callback".